# Refering to named constant in ARM assembly syntax / gas?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

When I try to compile this ARM asm with `as` (arm-linux-gnueabihf):

```
.data

len = 42

.text

    mov r0, #13
```

...it works.  However, when I replace `#13` with `=len`:

```
.data

len = 42

.text

    mov r0, =len
```

I get:

```
Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `mov r0,=len'
```

I've tried `#len` and `#=len`, neither seem to work.  How do I refer to a named constants from the `.data` section in the `.text` section in ARM syntax?

### Update:

Yeah, I had gotten section addresses and constants confused.  For posterity, here is ARM hello world in unified syntax:

```
.syntax unified

.data

msg:
  .ascii      "Hello, ARM!\n"
len = . - msg

.text

.globl _start
_start:
  mov r0, 1
  ldr r1, =msg
  mov r2, len
  mov r7, 4
  svc 0
  mov r0, 0
  mov r7, 1
  svc 0
```

Comment: Using `mov r0,#len` works for me. Also, the symbol `len` isn't in any section. A symbol needs to refer to storage to be in a section, `len = 42` doesn't create any storage.

Comment: @RossRidge: Solved, see update.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should put the answer to "answer" part and mark it as accepted, it makes it clearer for anyone from the future with similar problem.

Comment: Mostly you just got the syntax mixed up - `mov rd, #imm` is an instruction which takes a valid immediate; `ldr rd, =imm` is a pseudo-op which either assembles to a `mov` or a literal load depending on whether `imm` can be represented as an immediate or not. There is no such syntax as `mov rd, =imm`, just as the error says.